# Lost prints from pthread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I start to use pthread of C++ and have made a simple exampe for multi threads(3). But what i see is that I always got prints from two threads. why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

int N=10;

void* run(void* arg) {  

  char* msg = (char*)arg;

  for(int i; i<=N; ++i) std::cout<<msg<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if (argc > 1) N = stoi(argv[1]);

  pthread_t t1,t2,t3;

  pthread_create(&t1,NULL,run,(void*)"xxx");
  pthread_create(&t2,NULL,run,(void*)"    howdy");
  pthread_create(&t3,NULL,run,(void*)"          wrold");

  pthread_join(t1,NULL);
  pthread_join(t2,NULL);
  pthread_join(t3,NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Prints like:

```
howdy
      wrold
howdy
      wrold
```

Comment: why c++11 tag when you use posix thread instead that `std::thread`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

For example on my machine it doesn't print anything at all.

- `i` is not initialized.
- `void* run` has to return something (e.g.: `return NULL;`)